# how to change the popup window config in typescript?

Tags: angular, margin, default, popupwindow

I'm using angular and I have a popup window in it, when I open it for the first time, it has the margin: default but I want margin: none. how can I do it?

and this is the code:

```
popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=150,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write(
  '<html><head></head><body onload="window.print();window.close()"><p>' + headContents + '</p> <div>' + innerContents + '</div> <table><tr>' + '<td>' + this.sign + '</td></tr><tr><td>' + this.sender + '</td></tr></table> </body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();
```

Comment: where is your code? what have your tried? post atleast code to understand your pronblem

Comment: @pardeep-jain I edited my post! it's a simple popup window

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng2-opd-popup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup) npm package for show popup
Install on your project:

```
npm i ng2-opd-popup
```

and then import into module

```
import {PopupModule} from 'ng2-opd-popup';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    PopupModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

and then use in component 
html:

```
  <popup  #popup1>
        Add your custom html elements here
    </popup>
    <button (click)="ClickButton()">show popup</button>
```

component :

```
  @ViewChild('popup1') popup1: Popup;


  constructor() { }

  ClickButton(){
    this.popup1.show();
  }
```